# Setup an SSL certificate on xampp mac

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I have downloaded xampp for mac, installed it and bought ssl certificat, but i'm having hard

times to install the ssl...

- Can someone computer wise explain to me step by step, easy how to set it up? please i have

searched google, but could not understand the way they did, please take your time to

explain...

Comment: Often times the supplier of your cert can provide basic instructions for installing the certificate into your web server.  These instructions from [comodo](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=264) explain installing it into Apache.  Usually you can just read through `httpd-ssl.conf` and set the relevant values for the crt, key, and ca-bundle from there.

Comment: Easy said then done, but i have three files : PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt domain_com.crt, where should i place them in httpd-ssl.conf???

Comment: You are missing one critical file, the private key (`.key`) file.  Probably you just need to set `SSLCertificateFile` to `domain_com.crt`, `SSLCACertificateFile` to `PositiveSSLCA2.crt` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` to the private key file you generated initially.  Apparently PositiveSSL is a reseller for Comodo, so their directions on installing an SSL cert into Apache should cover everything.

Comment: They didn't mail me the .key file... where is that?

Comment: It should have been one of the first files you created when creating the CSR (certificate signing request).  You end up with a `.key` file and a `.csr` file.  Only you have the key file, you don't provide it to anyone for any reason.  If the key file is lost, you have to start the CSR process over again and get a new SSL cert.  If your key file is exposed, anyone can forge your SSL certificate.

Comment: I have used: http://www.gogetssl.com/eng/support/online_csr_generator/ to make the key, but they didn't mail me any file just the key in text and csr in text

Comment: Ok if you still have the key file in plain text, save that to your server and use that for `SSLCertificateKeyFile`.

Comment: Can i call it anything or does it need a special name???

Comment: Name doesn't matter, anything is fine.  Just use the `.key` extension so people know what it is.  In a production environment, chmod it to something like `400` so no other user can read the file and make sure `root` is the owner.  On your local host, probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, i did everything as you told me step by step, then i turned Apache on and went to " localhost ", but there was no ssl connection

Comment: What domain name is your SSL cert issued to?  It will only work for that hostname, probably not for localhost, or you will always get a cert error saying the host doesn't match, but most likely Apache won't try to serve the SSL request because the host doesn't match.  But anyway, try explicitly going to `https://localhost`, note the https in front.

Comment: I found the problem, i had to say: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp enablessl, but now it says: Syntax error on line 107 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/Applications/XAMPP/etc/ssl.key/signin.key' does not exist or is empty    and the file is there..

Comment: Make sure the user running as the server can access that file (permissions/ownership).  What is the first line of the `signin.key` file look like?

Comment: Its: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- now it works after using the right key file, using sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp disablessl and sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp enablessl , thanks to you!! make answer and let me accept you!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear its working now.  I added an answer for you.  Feel free to post an edit if you feel there is something else that should go in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file you need to edit to enable SSL is `httpd-ssl.conf` found in the `conf/extra` directory.

Change the following directives:

- `SSLCertificateFile` to `domain_com.crt`
- `SSLCACertificateFile` to `PositiveSSLCA2.crt`
- `SSLCertificateKeyFile` to the private key file you received when you created the CSR

  - Open " **Terminal** " and type:  `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` then add `127.0.0.1 your_domain.com` and `127.0.0.1 www.your_domain.com`, when done editing the hosts file, press **control-o** to save the file.

Then call `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp enablessl` to enable SSL in httpd.conf and restart Apache.  Now try accessing `https://localhost`

Comment: You helped me setup SSL, but now i'm facing a problem... - i'm trying to use my domain that i bought i have set it as " url frame " pointed to " localhost " just to test it...  it open the website, but it dont load https:// it only http://, but when i'm using https://localhost/ alone the SSl show up and load page, please help me again with this last step

Comment: I'm not sure exactly the set up you are talking about.  But you won't be able to use https:// on your actual domain name unless it is configured with the SSL certificate.  Maybe post on pastebin the HTML for the frame you are talking about.

Comment: I cant use SSL when i'm typing : https://domain.com/ it keep loading, but when i'm testing on my localhost https://localhost/ it active the SSL -

Comment: I found the last step: open " Terminal " and type: " sudo nano /private/etc/hosts " then add 127.0.0.1      your_domain.com and  127.0.0.1      www.your_domain.com , when done editing the hosts file, press control-o to save the file.

Comment: what is CSR that you mean ?