# Localhost - OpenSSL in Xamp Mac OSX

Tags: apache, ssl

First, I got localhost.csr, localhost.key and localhost.crt using the following commands on terminal:

Request:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.csr
```

Certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr -signkey localhost.key -out localhost.crt
```

I followed this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377651/setup-an-ssl-certificate-on-xampp-mac) and updates these `directives` things on httpd-ssl.conf:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/ssl-certs/localhost.key"
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/ssl-certs/localhost.crt"
```

In MyApache, SSL is enabled. When I restart localhost and go to `http://localhost`, the green sign appears but I get:

```
Access Forbidden Error 403
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
```

If I use plain `http://localhost`, the site loads fine.

Please let me know my faults. I am new to the SSL things and directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out that Virtual Hosts for two different Ports have to be set as:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/tikadattapahadi/web"
    <Directory  "/Users/tikadattapahadi/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost localhost:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ServerName localhost

    SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/ssl-certs/localhost.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/ssl-certs/localhost.key"


    DocumentRoot "/Users/tikadattapahadi/web/"
    <Directory "/Users/tikadattapahadi/web/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```